# select @variable=case when...end from... order by len(@variable)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008r2-express

What I'm trying to do is concatenate two fields of a table, sort them by the descending length of the concatenated fields and get the top result...

Here's the SQL I'm using to try and achieve this...

```
declare @color nvarchar(255);
declare @board_name nvarchar(255);

select top(1)
    @board_name = board_name, 
    @color = base_color + case when shade_color is null then '' else '/' + shade_color end 
from 
    cut_vinyl
order by 
    len(@color) desc;

select @board_name, @color;
```

So, if I had the following table for `cut_vinyl`

```
board_name | base_color | shade_color
=====================================
board0001  | clear      | NULL
board0002  | clear      | blue
board0003  | bronze     | bronze
board0004  | bronze     | green
board0005  | bronze     | blue
board0006  | bronze     | NULL
```

Then I would expect **`@board_name`** to be **board0003** and **`@color`** to be **bronze/bronze**, yet what I seem to be getting instead is a result like **`@board_name`** = **board0001**, and **`@color`** = **clear**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ordering on a `variable`:

```
order by 
    len(@color) desc;
```

If you're looking for the longest color, use:

```
order by 
    len(base_color) + len(shade_color) desc;
```

instead.

Comment: Given the table above, the result I expect should only ever return **board0003**. I don't just need the longest `base_color`, I need the longest `base_color + '/' + shade_color`.

Comment: That's right if you also order on the length of `shade_color`.  I've edited the answer.